# Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory. When using dynamic seed in anchor

Tags: anchor

I am getting and memory allocation failed error when I am passing in a dynamic seed for my account initialization.

This is how i use it:

```
pub fn chop_tree(ctx: Context<ChopTree>, counter: u16, levelSeed: String) -> Result<()> {
    chop_tree::chop_tree(ctx, counter)
}
```

and this is the anchor part:

```
#[derive(Accounts, Session)]
#[instruction(levelSeed: String)]
pub struct ChopTree<'info> {
    
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 1000,
        seeds = [levelSeed.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub game_data: Account<'info, GameData>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

On chain I see this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to have the string seed as first parameter like so:

```
pub fn chop_tree(ctx: Context<ChopTree>, levelSeed: String, counter: u16) -> Result<()> {
        chop_tree::chop_tree(ctx, counter)
    }
```

If someone can explain me how that results into an out of memory error would be interesting. Maybe a problem in anchor somewhere.

Comment: That's really bizarre... maybe you can try passing by reference to avoid moving the whole string into the function? Ie declare `levelSeed: &str` instead of `levelSeed: String`