# why "Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory" error?

Tags: anchor, account

I have a program that use to store configuration, as show bellow.

All work well except that, 'set_fee' function throw error:

```
> Program logged: "Instruction: SetFee"
> Program logged: "Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory"
> Program consumed: 1796 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: "SBF program panicked"
```

Can someone spot out where I have possibly done wrong?

```
#[program]
pub mod MyConf {

    use super::*;

    pub fn add_domain(ctx: Context<DomainAdd>, domain: u32, name: String ) -> Result<()> {
        // ...
            let domain_account: &mut Account<'_, DomainData> = &mut ctx.accounts.domain_account;
            domain_account.name = name;            
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_domain(ctx: Context<DomainGet>, domain: u32) -> Result<String> {
        let _domain_account: & Account<'_, DomainData> = & ctx.accounts.domain_account;
        Ok(String::from("tester"))
        // Ok(_domain_account.name)       // TODO: This also a issue that I unable to let it compile. It complains "cannot move out of dereference of"
    }    

    pub fn set_fee(ctx: Context<FeeSet>, fee: u64,  name: String ) -> Result<()> {  // <== THIS failed! Error: "memory allocation failed, out of memory"
        msg!("admin_board::set fee to {} for user: {}", fee, name);
        msg!("admin_board::set_fee() ctx.accounts.admin is: {:?}", ctx.accounts.admin.key());
        
        require!(ctx.accounts.admin_roles_account.admins.contains(ctx.accounts.admin.key), Errors::NotAnOwner);

        let fee_account: &mut Account<'_, FeeData> = &mut ctx.accounts.fee_account;
        fee_account.fee = fee;  
        Ok(())
    }    

    pub fn get_fee(ctx: Context<FeeGet>, domain: u32, name: String ) -> Result<u64> {
        let fee_account : &Account<'_, FeeData>  = &ctx.accounts.fee_account;    
        msg!("admin_board::get_fee() return fee value: {}", fee_account.fee);    
        Ok(fee_account.fee)
    }

}

  ...

 // ===========================  Account and Data Struct Begin ======================

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: String)]
pub struct FeeSet<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]  // mut is must in order to pay init gas fee
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        space = 8 + FeeData::INIT_SPACE + 8,  // This is slightly more space than FeeData struct actually need.
        payer = admin,
        seeds=[ b"FeeData", name.as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub fee_account: Account<'info, FeeData>,

    #[account(
        seeds = [ b"admin_roles"], // ensure no other fake PDA can call this function
        bump,
    )]
    pub admin_roles_account: Account<'info, AdminRoleSet>,  

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,  
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(domain: u32, name: String)]
pub struct FeeGet<'info> {
    #[account(
        constraint = name == domain_account.name, 
        seeds=[ b"DomainData", domain.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub domain_account: Account<'info, DomainData>,
        
    #[account(
        seeds=[ b"FeeData", name.as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]    
    pub fee_account: Account<'info, FeeData>,
}


#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct DomainData {
    #[max_len(256)]
    pub name: String, // 4 bytes + 256 bytes    
}


#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct FeeData {
    pub fee: u64,
}


#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct AdminRoleSet {
    admins: [Pubkey;3], // 32 bytes * N 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after second round browse on this forum, I found this post
[memory allocation failed, out of memory. When using dynamic seed in anchor](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/error-memory-allocation-failed-out-of-memory-when-using-dynamic-seed-in-ancho) share a common issue with me.

Also, I watch bellow statement from one post:

> You can access the instruction's arguments with the `#[instruction(..)]` attribute. **You have to list them in the same order as in the instruction but you can omit all arguments after the last one you need.**

So, for my issue, just change `set_fee` parameter order, let it be `ctx: Context<FeeSet>, name: String,fee: u64`, then problem solved.